# cookies are returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying a simple cookie exercise and when i hit submit it returns undefined. Also is there a way to check what in a cookie in visual studio code?

```
function setcookie()
{
   var tmr = new Date();
    tmr.setDate(tmr.getDate() + 1);
    document.cookie = "username="+ document.getElementById("username").innerHTML +";path=/";
    document.cookie = "password="+ document.getElementById("password").value +";path=/";
}

function getcookie()
{
   var Carray = document.cookie.split(";");


   for(i = 0 ; i < Carray.length ; i++)
   {
        var valuearray =Carray[i].split("=")


        if (valuearray == "username")
        {
            var name = valuearray[1];
        }
        else if (valuearray == "password")
        {
            var password = valuearray[1];
        }
   }
   alert("username is " + name +" password is " + password);

}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valuearray` will be a array, so you need to check `valuearray[0]` in the if condition.

```
var valuearray = Carray[i].split("=")
if (valuearray[0] == "username"){ //Here, valuearray[0]
  var name = valuearray[1];
} else if (valuearray[0] == "password"){
  var password = valuearray[1];
}
```

Comment: it still come up as undefined even after i changed it to an array, could it be an input issue?

Comment: i'm dumb and my id is different from my elementId, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function getcookie() {
  const Carray = document.cookie.split(";");
  const [name, password] = Carray.map(item => item.split('=')[1])
  console.log("username is " + name +" password is " + password);
}
```

or if you want to transform your cookies into object use this code

```
function getcookie()
{
   var Carray = document.cookie.split(";");
   var cookieObj = Carray.reduce((cookieObj, current) => {
    const [key, value] = current.split('=');
    return { ...cookieObj, ...{ [key]: value } }
   }, {})
   console.log("username is " + cookieObj.username +" password is " + cookieObj.password);
   return cookieObj;
}

// result
{
  username: 'usersname'
  password: 'userspassword'
}
```

Please return your result from the functions, I'm not returning anything because I'm trying to match your code.

and answer to your second question. yes you can get value from vscode but for that you need to start your debugging mode

Comment: I found the second part of your answer is exactly what I needed, but in the return statement I changed [key] to [key.trimStart()] to get it to work correctly. With more than one cookie, the document.cookie.split(";") was leaving a blank in front of any cookie names after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

name and password are declared in the block of for, but you use them in out of the block.
change getcookie function to this:

```
var name="";
var password ="";
for(i = 0 ; i < Carray.length ; i++)
   {
        var valuearray =Carray[i].split("=") 
        if (valuearray == "username")
        {
            name = valuearray[1];
        }
        else if (valuearray == "password")
        {
            password = valuearray[1];
        }
   }
   alert("username is " + name +" password is " + password);
```